# Any good fish books out there?

Tags: ichthyology

I recently read "What a Fish Knows: The Inner Lives of Our Underwater Cousins" by Jonathan Balcombe. The first part was the best where the author explained how fish are very advanced creatures because they have been around a lot longer than other vetebrates.

Are there any other books out there similar to this one? There seem to be tons of bird research books. Of course, birds are relatively easier to study than fish. (Their size and ability to fly makes them difficult to track. But, at least they are not underwater and sometimes stay in one area for awhile. Fish are pretty much constantly on the move.)

I am not really looking for a text book unless you know of one that is interesting to read and not just a list of facts...unless a text book would be a good place to start.

I have read Colin Tudge's books on trees and birds. I wish he would write one on fish.

Answer (score 1):

As a fisheries biologist these are what I would recommend to read.These are all science entertainment books(i.e., factual, but fun to read).The first 2 are more fish biology. The second  2 is more fisheries ecology.

1. Your Inner Fish: A Journey Into the 3.5-Billion-Year History of the human body. 
   Neil shubin
2. Demon Fish
   Juliet Eilperin
3. Four Fish: The Future of the Last Wild Food
   Paul Greenberg
4. Cod: A Biography Of The Fish That Changed The World
   Mark kurlansky